# How to get current windows username and disable the credentials prompting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis

I have a C#.NET 4.0 application running under IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 with IIS7 server. The application will run in the company intranet that automatically grabs the logged-in Windows username of the person viewing the page without being prompted to enter credentials when the page loads. Now i'm facing 2 problems:

1) Currently, the apps returns the production server name (eg: XYZ\sam) that the application located at. I want to get the current logged on username (eg: ABC\sam). It works fine at localhost but not at production server.

I've enabled `<authentication mode="Windows" />` at web.config , enabled windows authentication and disabled anonymous authentication at IIS.

I've tried `Page.User.Identity.Name`, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`, and others but still failed to get the right name. How to get the current windows logged on user?

2) When I want to access the application, it keeps prompting out a windows for username and password. If I ignore it, it will prompt out

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You
>   do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

How i gona fix it?

Comment: System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials?

Comment: @Sudhakar thanks for your reply. Can you explain more about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, it cannot retrieve the logged in username because the server is domain server. It works after transfer from workgroup to domain.

For question 2, it works fine(no pop out credential) if I access with the server name (eg:servername/appsname). But it will ask for credential if I use ip (eg:xxx.xx.xx.x/appsname) and didn't setup the tools internet options. Factor still not known.

Answer (score 0):

For your 2 problem, to log automatically, you have to set it on the browser, for my experience, i have done this in IE: https://superuser.com/questions/537416/how-to-make-internet-explorer-automatically-login-in-a-certain-domain

Comment: Please help yourself by adding the substantial content from your link to your answer. Linking to another site to "find the answer" is less than ideal for SO users and results in a less valuable answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I added the site like dis - "HTTP://xxx.xx.x.xx" But it still prompting out the credential windows.

Comment: @GG90 , give a try to this: go to IE internet options-> Security Tab ->Custom Level -> then at the bottom of the settings there is the "User authentication" , select "Authomatic logon with current user...."

Comment: @GG90 you have to be logged on the pc with the same credentials for your site.